# Restart/Pause/Resume ARCore sessions in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

How do I go about pausing/resuming session in ARCore? I have a set of canvases which I am constantly switching between. Only a few of these canvases use ARCore.

How do I implement ARCore service in these canvases?

I also want to clear the ARCore data on switching to other canvases.

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47343239/pause-google-arcore-in-unity

Comment: @alikanat That question is to delete an anchor created by the session , I want to pause/restart the whole session itself

Answer (score 1):

**At the moment there are no other methods in Unity to pause/resume an ARCore sessions**.

For restarting ARCore session in Unity you can use one of two methods: `Destroy(session)` or `DestroyImmediate(session)`. One of these methods could definitely work for you.

```
ARCoreSession session = goARCoreDevice.GetComponent<ARCoreSession>();
ARCoreSessionConfig myConfig = session.SessionConfig;

DestroyImmediate(session);
// Destroy(session);
yield return null;

session = goARCoreDevice.AddComponent<ARCoreSession>();
session.SessionConfig = myConfig;
session.enabled = true;
```

Here's a Unity documentation for [Object.DestroyImmediate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html) and [Object.Destroy()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) functions.